# How to cache data in the service?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a service in my Angular application that fetches specific data. For this reason, this service offers a method called `getData():Observable<Data>`.

However, it should also contain two or three other methods that provide subsets or filtered data.

It seems strange to me to call `getData()` multiple times just to pass the result to `getFilteredData(data$)`.
But it also doesn't seem right to me to let the `getFilteredData()` call the `getData()` method independently, since these would be redundant queries.

How can I remember the result of `getData()` (considering the Angular style guide)?

```typescript
export class DataService {

  getData():Observable<Data> {
   //...
  }


  getFilteredData():Observable<Data> {
     return this.getData().pipe( //<--- redundant call of getData() since Ive already used getData() at this point in my app
        //...
     );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked the right qeustion. I suggest you to make a new property with a `BehaviorSubject` type as your state trigger. And another one to share the data - this allows you reuse the state value when it needs. Your code should look like this:

```
export class DataService {

  readonly data$: Observable<Data>;

  private readonly getNewData = new BehaviorSubject<Params>({});

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.data$ = this.getNewData.pipe(
      switchMap(params => this.client.get(..., params)),
      shareReplay(1),
    );
  }

  getData(params: Params):Observable<Data> {
    this.getNewData.next(params);

    return this.data$.pipe(first());
  }


  getFilteredData():Observable<Data> {
     return this.data$.pipe(
        //...
     );
  }

}
```

You can use `data$` directly to get data, or just use return value from `getData` method.

Comment: The key point here isn't BehaviorSubject, but the operator shareReplay. Search after it and you will understand it.

Comment: @derstauner You may see `shareReplay` in my solution as well

Comment: Yes, I saw this. I just wanted to make the note, that essentially `shareReplay` does the caching.